# Filtering an aggregated chart with another aggregation field

Tags: group-by, filtering, vega-lite, altair

I'm trying to produce something similar to the [K-top](https://observablehq.com/@manzt/top-k-plot-with-others-vega-lite-example) example.

Except that instead of filtering out and displaying the **same aggregated field** data, I want:

- to display one type of aggregated data (the max of daily temps)
- and filter on **another aggregation field** ( the mean of daily temps)

I've created an observable notebook [here](https://observablehq.com/d/e4e03162dbadce09) to build my test case, and this is how far I got.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "as": "month_date"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "mean", "field": "precipitation", "as": "mean_precipitation"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "precipitation", "as": "max_precipitation"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["month_date"]
    },
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"as": "aggregation", "field": "precipitation", "op": "mean"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["month_date"]
    },
    {"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}]},
    {"calculate": "datum.rank <= 100? datum.month_date : null", "as": "dates"},
    {"filter": "datum.dates != null"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "dates", "type": "ordinal", "timeUnit": "month"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "max",
          "field": "precipitation",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "tick",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "precipitation",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "size": {"value": 15}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I feel I'm missing something link the `GroupBy.ngroup` from `pandas.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following Vega-Lite's [Filtering Top-K Items](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/window_top_k.html) example along with an extra aggregate transform. Here is an example adapting your spec from above ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-zNh8jgAGRgD2Q7bue6ZMWs-4rM+v5vkR8AKihgFKOGx7WqB6bgdGmpJjOaL9oiBoZlmmHYTSiL4WxAHhmIlTiRQ+asCRbjDGpRawIwABeX7hDpYh6XovoAKwsesjlgCxjK5EAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": "Top Months by Mean Precipitation",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "as": "month_date"},
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "mean", "field": "precipitation", "as": "mean_precipitation"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "precipitation", "as": "max_precipitation"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["month_date"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "mean_precipitation", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank < 10"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "month_date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "title": "month (descending by max precip)",
      "sort": {
        "field": "max_precipitation",
        "op": "average",
        "order": "descending"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "mean_precipitation",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "precipitation (mean & max)"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "tick",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "max_precipitation", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "size": {"value": 15}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jake.  I was getting confused on how to use joinaggregate and aggregate.  Your example makes it very clear.

Comment: but I link here another question that your example also brings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153985/clamping-y-axis-when-layering-aggregated-charts-in-vega-lite  Why is the y-axis clamped at 10 not showing the full hight of the max-precipitation ?

Comment: I link here the notebook with the a complete answer https://observablehq.com/@maliky/vega-lite-filtering-top-k-aggregated-fields-by-another-aggr  Thank you again