# Clamping y-axis when layering aggregated charts in vega-lite

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite

This is a follow up from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151507/filtering-an-aggregated-chart-with-another-aggregation-field) for which I built a test case in a (hopefully now public) [notebook](https://observablehq.com/@maliky/vega-lite-filtering-top-k-aggregated-fields-by-another-aggr) and noticed the following behavior:

At the end of the notebook, in the section **bugs** you will notice that `y-axis` of the `max_precipitation` of the layered chart using is clamped to 10.

I tried changing the domain but the *bars* do not go above 10.

Here the code example in [vega-lite's editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-ALS7i5BcblbRBmZAxOhrJOwHUDsqMC4FWEiiGw1B2OhJczY47na6m83INY3WOWzC21S0VXEQaX8HQzEAEdWAcLQsUYKg62bTRtFPG4MW7f48w+RwADIwHLWsxyXINsLWK8Vj3C9D2g+AFTTB0lCdOdrXvINHzdTVfXbE5OwRMCDT-WCgJAxEIPw2MnTESoGIoKNWFgtxhn49NYEYAAvU9wlEsRxL0ABGABWXD1m0sBcMZXIgA) reproduced below:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": "Top Months by Mean Precipitation",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "as": "month_date"},
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "mean", "field": "precipitation", "as": "mean_precipitation"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "precipitation", "as": "max_precipitation"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["month_date"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "mean_precipitation", "order": "descending"}]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "month_date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "title": "month (descending by max precip)",
      "sort": {
        "field": "max_precipitation",
        "op": "average",
        "order": "descending"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "max_precipitation",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "precipitation (mean & max)"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "tick",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "mean_precipitation", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "size": {"value": 15}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the precipitation column is being parsed as strings rather than as numbers. You can specify the parsing format for the column using :

```
"data": {
  "url": "data/seattle-weather.csv",
  "format": {"parse": {"precipitation": "number"}}
},
```

The result is [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-3JTdOSZXd3iAitIAAR1YBwO2aKg5zg+tOzwqd8WUPssUcAAyMBx1nM8n0fRVBR-d4MBcAD63ga060gpRE2HRCKMgBCalXSFsRo7c-BhXCYkI4j8TIl84MgRMxEKUpIAoGtWDwtwjm07NYEYAAvCtwmMsRTL0ABGABWDjnk8p8FT6IA):

[image]

Comment: What pointed the answer to you beside experience?  Why was 10 the maximun for y-axis ?

Comment: I looked in the data viewer on the vega editor and saw that the values are represented as strings - this is sometimes a problem with data stored as CSV rather than as JSON.